# display: flex; does not work with <summary> on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser, mobile-safari

I want to use `display: flex` with `<summary></summary>`. On other browsers, Chrome, Firefox, etc., the flex children work normally. (They stay in the same line) But on Safari (v12.0, both mobile & desktop), the children stay on different lines.

This is what it looks like on other browsers compared against Safari.

[image]

What should I do to get flexbox working properly like other browsers?

Thanks!

```css
summary {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <div>flex-a</div>
    <div>flex-b</div>
  </summary>
  <p>some content</p>
</details>
```

Comment: I guess you would have to wrap the summary content in a div and put flex on that - but is it semantically correct?

Comment: @Pete I don't think wrapping it with a div is semantically incorrect since it's used within the `<detail></detail>` tags (unlike the linked questions that use outside `<detail></detail>`.

Comment: I'm talking about the use of what looks like 2 headings in a summary tag - surely it should just be one summary